# Is it possible to use cloudformation to update a queue created through the aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I have created an SQS queue using the aws sdk in java. I want to migrate the queue for dev into my yaml cloudformation file. Test uses cloudformation already.

After adding dev to the list of regions that the queue is created for in cloudformation I get an error:

`A queue already exists with that name and different tags`

I have created a new queue to test with in dev through cloudformation which gets created with 3 tags.
The old queue had 0 tags but I manually added the 3 tags through the console UI to be identical and yet the error persists.

Is this an issue with the tags not being present in the previous cloudformation template as the queue was not initallly created using cloudformation?

Edit:
The queue exists in my cloudformation already but dev is not included in the if::equals function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) your SQS queue into CloudFormation stack.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for your answer. I have updated my question. I was not accurate enough in my unedited question.